# Can sbt-native-packager package many server applications in one deb package?

Tags: scala, sbt, packaging, sbt-native-packager

Can sbt-native-packager package many server applications with generating many start scripts in one deb package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packaging multiple applications is possible via sbt sub modules. Aggregate all the projects and you'll end up with a package containing all the application jars.

Multiple entrypoints are currently on the way. You can follow the progress here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/pull/839

Cheers,
Muki